# Adding menu item to Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, menu, navigation, e-commerce, spree

I've created a spree site and using spree_essentials and spree_essentials blog have added a blog to my site. How can I add a link to the blog from my main navigation?

I've created an extension for customization called Theme. It placed this folder into my main project folder rather than in to vendor/extensions not sure if that matters or not.

Pretty new to rails and Spree.

Here's the link for the extensions I used: https://github.com/citrus/spree_essential_blog

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want add a hook inside **lib/your_extension_hooks.rb**, something like this :

```
insert_after : sidebar do
    # you can add a partial too ^^ 
    %(<label>test</label>)
end
```

You can find all available hook [here](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/hooks.html).